# Agora.io RTC in flutter

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I have two flutter applications. One is for the doctors other one is for the patients. App IDs of the apps are different.
Now, how can I communicate through video calling from one app to another?

Answer (score 0):

In order to let both apps communicate with each other, you need to use same appid on both apps and join the same channel.

Answer (score 0):

As shaocheng-yang said you need the same app-id from both sides and the same channel name to connect and start a video call.

There is a full example available on Github [here](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart)
Take look at it.

Download code and change app-id just for testing purposes.

Comment: If I use same app ID in both apps they might not be considered as different apps. I mean then I have only one single app. But I need two apps to upload on play store.

Comment: I am meaning with app ID is the package name for android